# SQL update for multiple database entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

we are using a commercial application, which is customizable. Front End is a webserver with MS SQL server in background.

We have an asset management, which with we can link some contracts.

Now I have to create a new workflow: An asset has a costcenter and all linked contracts to this object have to migrate the costcenter dialy night automatically.

For example that's my view "View_Info" to get needed information:

```
IDAsset - IDContract - ConstCenterAsset

111       222          333
111       223          333
112       224          334
113       225          335
....
```

And my main table "Contract":

```
ID - CostCenter

222    000
223    000
224    000
225    000
```

I know how to update one entry in "Contract" table with SQL UPDATE command...

But how can I do it for all existing entries...

I have to update about 1000 DB entries dialy night...

Answer (score 1):

You can `UPDATE` with `JOIN` like this:

```
UPDATE c 
SET c.CostCenter = v.ConstCenterAsset
FROM Contract as c 
INNER JOIN View_Info as v ON v.IDContract = c.ID;
```

This way, all the table `Contract`' entries will be updated from the view `View_Info`. You can also add extra `WHERE` clause at the end to limit the entries which should be updated.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it this afternoon :) I thought that a for loop or anything like this is needed to update alle entries.